# jQuery retract usage affects other div tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a dropdown box using the jquery. It's working well. I also implemented the option to hide the dropdown list when we click in any other position of the page after opening the list. I have used the following jQuery for that.

```
$('div.selectBox').each(function(){
    $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
    $(this).attr('value',$(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));
    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','block');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','none');
        }
    });
    $(document).unbind('click');
    $(document).click(function(event){
        if($(event.target).closest('div.selectBox').length == 0) {
             $('.selectOptions').hide();                
        }
    });
    $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
        $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

It closes or hides perfectly when we click in any other part of the site. But the problem is some other `<div>` tags are becoming hidden or `display:none;` after performing this operation.

Please advise me a solution for this. You can see it affects completely in the above url. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Can you put a minimum (non)-working example on jsfiddle / jsbin? It could be something with identical class names. However, I cannot figure out the connection between the class names in code and on the website.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TUEMq/
You can see that when we click on the create new button,the search box disappears!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).toggleClass('open').next().toggle();
```

This line in the various places its scattered through your code appears to be causing the issue. I'm not sure what it was originally intended to accomplish. It may need amended or just out right removing depending on what the intention for it was.

**Edit**

After playing with your jsFiddle I can see its intention was to toggle the nested child element and needs changing to `$(this).toggleClass('open');` to work properlly

Comment: The problem is that .next().toggle() toggles the display of the next (sibling) element, which happens to be the one that comes after createNew - either the search box or the date picker, in your examples.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle page. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/TUEMq/18/
The top username dropdown opens for a while and closes automatically.

Comment: The dropdown menu hyperlinks are not working. I think it closes the list without linking on to the hyperlink!!!! Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

## jsFiddle

 [<sup>***Updated 9/21/2012 to reflect some of the other uses including a second menu without having 2 open at once***</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/m6vak/)

Long story short, I'm not including all your other work, but for the BASE functionality u want all you need is the following:

```
$(function() {
    // This will ensure it closes when clicked anywhere not on the element or its children
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $(".open").removeClass("open");
    });

// the simple task of adding class
$(".createNew, .username, .notes").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // This next line ensures not having 2 open at once
    $(".open").filter(function(i){ return $this[0] != $(this)[0]; }).removeClass("open");
    e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents it closing via document.click
    $this.toggleClass("open");
});
});
```

if you wanted to use on multiple elements of dif class names:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $(".createNew, .username, .notes").removeClass("open");
    });

    // the simple task of adding class
    $(".createNew, .username, .notes").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents it closing via document.click
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });

    // the rest
    $(".textbox").css({width:'100px', height: '33px'})
        .focus(function(e) {
            $(this).animate({width: '200px', height: '33px'});
        })
        .blur(function(e) {
            $(this).animate({width: '100px', height: '33px'});
        });
});
```

Comment: In your example you are missing the opening of the dropdown list of createNew.

Comment: @Narretz no i'm not, in his fiddle, open is controlled via css, thus only the class need be added as you can see here [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/m6vak/)

Comment: You are correct, sorry. It's an interesting way to do it, though I'd file it under "unintuitive". :) (I know that it was 99tharun, not you)

Comment: i simply instruct what is there, no reason to confuse the already befuddled :P

Comment: I tried with the code. It works good in the `createNew` class. But not for `username`. The menu is not opening. When we click many times continuously, we can see it opening for a small fraction of second. 
http://tharunjose.com/stack/

Comment: In your fiddle, you are not selecting the .username class in the click functions. There is also an error with the css selectors, because the username div contains a link. At least for me, the dropdown will disappear after a few seconds when the <a> tag is present. http://jsfiddle.net/TUEMq/23/

Comment: The dropdown menu hyperlinks are not working. I think it closes the list without linking on to the hyperlink!!!! Any solution? –

Comment: In the fiddle, there is no link in the <a> tag

Comment: @99tharun Hey, I see the dropdown recoil issue you had, I fixed it in my fiddle.  The problem was simple, Even tho your a tag had no href url, it was still producing "action". To alleviate the problem, us a standard practice: Anytime you have an A tag with NO link, simply put `javascript: void(0)` for the href link. Example: `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Username &#9660; </a>`. This will cancel out ALL browser action with the tag thus freeing up your abilities